# How to initialize a BLE device in order to send some string?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to write some app which sends data to `BLE` module on `arduino`.

I have already made a connection with this module using commands

```
Gatt = myDevice.connectGatt(this, true, gattCallback);
```

What should I write in order to send some string to `BLE` module?

Comment: Have you tried to discover services followed by writing to a found characteristic? You should be able to follow any Android BLE tutorial / example. If you encounter some problem, feel free to edit the question so it becomes answerable.